# convert a String[] to Arraylist<String> with java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to convert a string that I get from a file, to an arraylist. I tried it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Data
{
    static File file = DataSaver.file;
    static List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(512);
    public static void a() throws Exception
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
        if(!file.exists())
        {
            throw new IOException("Datafile not found.");
        }
        else
        {
            String[] string = reader.readLine().split("$");
            for(int i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
            {
                data.add(string[i]);
            }
        }
        dis.close();
        System.out.println(data.toString()); //for debugging purposes.
    }
}
```

Ouput:
`[$testdata1$testdata2$]`

Wanted output:
`[testdata1, testdata2]`

File content:
`$testdata1$testdata2$`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why are you calling an array of `String` 'string'?

Comment: Why not? You have a problem with the word 'string'?

Comment: It's a bad variable name. Java may allow it because it's not case-sensitive with it's classes, but that wouldn't work in C# (where `string` is an alias for `String`). Furthermore, it doesn't really describe what's contained in the variable.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream if you want to read text, its more confusing than useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String.split` takes a regex and `$` is a special char that need to be escaped. Also, the first char is a `$` so splitting would end up with an empty first element (you need to remove it somehow, this is one way:

```
String[] string = reader.readLine().substring(1).split("\\$");
```

...or:

```
String[] string = reader.readLine().split("\\$");
for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
    if (!string[i].isEmpty())
        data.add(string[i]);
```

Comment: No problem @user1546467, glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Use `("\\$")` to remove the special meaning of `"$"`.

**2.** Use `Arrays.asList()` for the **Conversion of** `Array` TO `ArrayList`

**From Java Docs :**

Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.

This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list initialized to contain several elements:

**eg:**

```
String[] string = reader.readLine().split("\\$");

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(string));
```

Comment: @dacwe Isnt the List from Arrays.asList() directly backed by the array? Which would mean almost no overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape special characters with `\\`.

Change your split statement like below

```
String[] string = reader.readLine().split("\\$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @dacwe

```
String[] string = reader.readLine().substring(1).split("\\$");
List<String> data =Arrays.asList(string);
```

Comment: If you want to contribute to his answer, edit it or leave a comment.

Comment: Alright, but @user1546467 wanted an `ArrayList` (`asList` returns a list backed by the array).